# CNContactPickerViewController on tab bar controller

Tags: ios, contacts, ios9, tabbar, picker

I'm using the **CNContactPickerViewController** to access contacts. And everything works fine until the part where I want to use this in Tabbar.
In previous ios versions replacing the view by the picker worked well but in ios 9 does not show anything.

When I use this code to present view the tabbar disappears.

```
[self presentViewController:my_picker animated:YES completion: nil];
```

I want have the tabbar always visible and the contacts list inside the tab.

Using **ABPeoplePickerNavigationController** I replace the view with the following code and it works fine.

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray [self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
int index = [controllers indexOfObject:self];

[controllers replaceObjectAtIndex: index withObject: picker];
```

Someone has a solution for this using?

Comment: Inacio Did you find solution to solve this problem?Please tell me how to show Tabbar view controller always in front of the contact picker view controller. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

Just use these lines into your code ,

```
my_picker.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;              

[self presentViewController:my_picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now the tabBar won't disappear from your screen